# prefix table and plugins

Tags: plugins, database

I changed my prefix of my tables from the wp_ to something else for security reasons and good practice etc.  I was curious most of new plugins installed take on the new prefix but I have one that refuses and still installs with wp_   it still works but i was curious is that normal practice or just a bad written plugin?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Just a badly written plugin.

Longer answer: When a plugin calls the database in the right/correct/best practice way it uses Global `$wpdb` instead of just naming the database table, for example:

**Wrong way**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE... "
```

**Right way**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE... "
```

this way it would work even if  you change your tables prefix.